# Parameter validation failed: Unknown parameter in Image.S3Object in AWS Rekognition

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rekognition

I want to retrieve the labels of an image named "sample.jpg" stored in a S3 Bucket named "bucket1"

Im following [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/images-s3.html) documentation in Python.

```
import boto3

def detect_labels(photo, bucket):

    client=boto3.client('rekognition')

    response = client.detect_labels(Image={'S3Object':{'Bucket':"bucket1",'Name':"sample.jpg"}},
        MaxLabels=10)

    print('Detected labels for ' + photo) 
    print()   
    for label in response['Labels']:
        print ("Label: " + label['Name'])
        print ("Confidence: " + str(label['Confidence']))
        print ("Instances:")
        for instance in label['Instances']:
            print ("  Bounding box")
            print ("    Top: " + str(instance['BoundingBox']['Top']))
            print ("    Left: " + str(instance['BoundingBox']['Left']))
            print ("    Width: " +  str(instance['BoundingBox']['Width']))
            print ("    Height: " +  str(instance['BoundingBox']['Height']))
            print ("  Confidence: " + str(instance['Confidence']))
            print()

        print ("Parents:")
        for parent in label['Parents']:
            print ("   " + parent['Name'])
        print ("----------")
        print ()
    return len(response['Labels'])


def main():
    photo=''
    bucket=''
    label_count=detect_labels(photo, bucket)
    print("Labels detected: " + str(label_count))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

But Iam getting the following error.

> Parameter validation failed: Unknown parameter in Image.S3Object:
>   "bucket1", must be one of: Bucket, Name, Version Unknown parameter in
>   Image.S3Object: "sample.jpg", must be one of: Bucket, Name,  Version*

Answer (score 0):

I have examined and tested your Python code snippet and I can confirm to the best of my ability there's nothing wrong with your code.

The successful response (depending on your image) should output something similar to:

```
Label: Car
Confidence: 99.52464294433594
Instances:
  Bounding box
    Top: 0.5000969767570496
    Left: 0.002728196792304516
    Width: 0.10333306342363358
    Height: 0.1907607913017273
  Confidence: 99.52464294433594

  Bounding box
    Top: 0.5250729322433472
    Left: 0.7276265621185303
    Width: 0.2508099675178528
    Height: 0.22016148269176483
  Confidence: 99.27792358398438

  ...
  ...

Labels detected: 10
```

From the error, the issue is more related to the boto3 version i.e you are most likely using an older version of boto3 hence the old version is not able to pick-up the required parameter [Image.S3Object](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/rekognition.html#Rekognition.Client.detect_labels)

Resolution Steps:

***1. Check the current version of boto3 :***

```
pip show boto3
```

or

```
pip3 show boto3
```

or

```
>>> import boto3
>>> boto3.__version__
```

If the output is anything less than the current version (1.12.39) then proceed to upgrade your boto3 version as shown below.

***2. Upgrade your boto3:***

```
pip install botocore --upgrade
pip install boto3 --upgrade
```

or

```
pip3 install botocore --upgrade
pip3 install boto3 --upgrade
```

Note: You'll need to log out for the changes to take effect

Hope this helps!